# How to return from http.get function

Tags: node.js

When I run the following, I get the correct console output but the value returned from the function is always 'undefined'

```js
    function get_public_ip() {
        http.get({
            'host': 'api.ipify.org',
            'port': 80,
            'path': '/'
        }, function (resp) {
            resp.on('data', function (ip) {
                console.log(ip.toString());  //outputs ip address
                return ip.toString();      // returns 'undefined'
            });
        });
    }

    async function run() {
        let pubip = await get_public_ip();
        // do stuff with pubip
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make `get_public_ip` return a promise

```
function get_public_ip() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    http.get({
      'host': 'api.ipify.org',
      'port': 80,
      'path': '/'
    }, function(resp) {
      resp.on('data', function(ip) {
        resolve(ip.toString());
      });
      resp.on('error', reject);
    });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `http.get` returns its data in **chunks**, and the `data` event supplies **just one** of perhaps **many** chunks, you need to ***accumulate*** the chunks and make sense of the aggregated chunks after receiving notification that you have them all, which comes from the `end` event.

It's also important to concatenate all the buffers **before** even trying to make sense of the data as a utf-8 string, because the bytes of multi-byte encoded characters may be split into two separate chunks.

The plan is:

- create a promise, which your function will return
- on `data` push the newly arrived buffer into an array
- on `end` concat the buffers and decode the utf-8 string, and resolve the promise
- on `error` reject the promise

```js
function get_public_ip() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    http.get({
      'host': 'api.ipify.org',
      'port': 80,
      'path': '/'
    }, function (res) {
      let buffers = [];
      res.on('data', buf => buffers.push(buf));
      res.on('end', () => resolve(Buffer.concat(buffers).toString('utf8')));
      res.on('error', reject);
    });
  });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use Like This.

```
 async function get_public_ip() {
   let data;
await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts").then((res) => {
    data = res;
    return res;
  });
  return data;
}

async function run() {
  let pubip = await get_public_ip();
  console.log(" pubip", pubip);
}
run();
```